# RSA_NO_PADDING is different between Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl, bouncycastle

In Java ,I use `Bouncy Castle` encrypt data using padding:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NOPADDING");
```

The Base64 encoded result is :

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.....H6hBDxOrCI0K8fd13vOYtsKdo4SI3VZTa3...
```

Ant it **won't change** every time.

And in C++, I use `OpenSSL` library to encrypt data :

```
RSA_public_encrypt(rsa_len, (unsigned char *)str, (unsigned char*)p_en, p_rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);
```

The Base64 encoded result is :

```
bxeeBPfFRJsLOzJLMS/qGKtDe1zPw8H491QsE+uuRRay6/ep69fqv386j8...
```

And it **will change** every time I run code.

I read Wiki and know [RSA encryption is a deterministic encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Padding).

So the result of java is reasonable and **my question is**:

1. Is "AAAAAAAA..." padding is **correct** for no padding of java?
2. What has openssl done in **C++** code to cause the result seems to have **padding** and time varying?

**Update**

I found that my java code is correct. 
And [When calling  RSA_private_encrypt with RSA_NO_PADDING, the input must 
have the same size as the RSA key modulus.](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/RSA-private-encrypt-does-not-work-with-RSA-NO-PADDING-option-td28763.html) .After I fill my input to 256 bytes , openssl can decrypt the java encrypt result.

**So, the question become to**:

What has openssl done to fill the input to reach the required length?

**Update**

At last, I don't have much time to research the OAEP in openssl.And the server use this unsafe way due to history problem. So I fill my input with byte 0.Just like:

```
This is input                         //<-----following many ASCII 0 char to reach 256 bytes length
```

But this will cause the output be the same. Any other code should prevent this in either server and client.

Comment: Initializing the `Cipher` instance is one thing, how do you _use_ it? Many errors come from misuse of this class, particularly (no offense meant, I'm serious) from C/C++ programmers who fail to grasp the difference between `char` and `byte` in Java. Show more code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And it will change every time I run code.

Yes. That's due to [Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding (OAEP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).

If you send the same message twice, like *Attack at dawn*, your adversary who observes the message won't be able to learn anything (or make an educated guess) when he sees the message again. The property is known as semantic security or [Ciphertext Indistinguishability (IND-CPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability).

Here's a related talk by Dr. Matt Green on PKCS padding versus OAEP padding. Its very approachable: [A bad couple of years for the cryptographic token industry](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/bad-couple-of-years-for-cryptographic.html).

---

> Is "AAAAAAAA..." padding is correct for no padding of java?

Possibly. I believe its just a string of leading 0x00 bytes that have been Base64 encoded.

---

> What has openssl done in C++ code to cause the result seems to have padding and time varying?

Its using OAEP.

---

> So, the question become to:
>   What has openssl done to fill the input to reach the required length?

Its using OAEP.

The question may become: why is Java not using it because lack of OAEP means you could leak information for each message encrypted.

Comment: It help me a lot!!!And now the server using OAEP because of history problem. And which OAEP padding should I use in java to match openssl?

Comment: @zzy - Try the string "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding" or "RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding". If that does not work, see [Is RSA PKCS1-OAEP padding supported in bouncycastle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17110217/608639) (I don't really use Java or Boubcy Castle, so I can't be of much help beyond basic interop problems).