# .NET System Encryption to Bouncy Castle Java Decryption Throws Error

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, encryption, bouncycastle

Tough question but I could use any help on it.

I'm using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml on my end to encrypt an XML SAML blob.

The encryption is working fine, however when it hits the java library on the other side they are getting error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.WrapCipherSpi.engineUnwrap(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:680)
        at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:611)
        at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:761)
        at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:512)
        at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:439)
        at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:400)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
```

How can I continue to use my encryption method:

```
        public XmlElement EncryptXml(XmlElement assertion, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        //cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\SEI.cer");
        XmlElement returnElement;
        EncryptedData message = new EncryptedData();
        message.Type = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element";
        message.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES128KeyWrapUrl);
        //message.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES128KeyWrapUrl);
        EncryptedKey key = new EncryptedKey();
        key.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);
        key.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

        var rKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        rKey.BlockSize = 128;
        rKey.KeySize = 128;
        rKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        key.CipherData.CipherValue = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(rKey.Key, (RSA)cert.PublicKey.Key, false);
        KeyInfoEncryptedKey keyInfo = new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(key);
        message.KeyInfo.AddClause(keyInfo);

        message.CipherData.CipherValue = new EncryptedXml().EncryptData(assertion, rKey, false);
        returnElement = message.GetXml();

        Logger("Cert Size: " + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(cert.ToString()));

        GetBytesKeyAndData(rKey, assertion.InnerText);


        return returnElement;
    }
```

While getting around this error? Is there a parameter on EncryptedKey to set the padding size? Or do I have to use Bouncy Castle to specify the size of the encrypted data?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the matching cert on the other side?  It sounds like you're using a cert for a bigger RSA modulus for encryption than for decryption.

Comment: so it's the certs that don't match up? no I'm not positive I don't know which certifcate they are using...should be the private key of the matching public that I was sent

Comment: Use Bouncy Castle specified size.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455208/2871356), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36560847/2871356) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2579225/2871356) post will be helpful.

Comment: thanks guys, I've ran through those posts and they do give some good high level info...I know I need the key to be longer than the message but my code blows up when I try and specify it as larger

Comment: What I'm needing is a direct implementation in C#

Comment: You are using in Java side an opensaml library to decrypt the AES key and the XML content, that is expected to work properly. The trace shows it is a problem decrypting the AES key with the RSA private key. It could not be a problem with the size of the encrypted data. As you have said that the key pair match, then the problem is in C# side. I have reviewed a full example of XML Dsig encryption using AEs key but I have not found substantial differences. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746(v=vs.110).aspx (i am not a c# programmer) could you test the `decrypt` method of example?

Comment: the padding may increase the size of the block that you are trying to encrypt.

Comment: I've played with changing the padding mode above, any idea what the enum should be?

Comment: Issue is at java end not C#

Comment: what would happen if you use **rKey.BlockSize = 96;**?

Comment: I now know the pain of java....solved it but still have no idea how the code is now working, changed one of the encryption params to 256 and decrypted succesfully in a java test environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the size of the keywrapurl for AES encryption of the RSA key.

Still don't really understand how encryption to the opensaml java library works, and after cracking it open I'm amazed at how long it takes to setup a simple test envrionment in java.

**Moral of the story: don't use assymetric encryption for lots of data.**

```
public XmlElement EncryptXml(XmlElement assertion, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        //cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\SEI.cer");
        XmlElement returnElement;
        EncryptedData message = new EncryptedData();
        message.Type = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element";
        message.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256KeyWrapUrl);
        //message.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES128KeyWrapUrl);
        EncryptedKey key = new EncryptedKey();
        key.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);
        key.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

        var rKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        rKey.BlockSize = 128;
        rKey.KeySize = 128;
        rKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        key.CipherData.CipherValue = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(rKey.Key, (RSA)cert.PublicKey.Key, false);
        KeyInfoEncryptedKey keyInfo = new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(key);
        message.KeyInfo.AddClause(keyInfo);

        message.CipherData.CipherValue = new EncryptedXml().EncryptData(assertion, rKey, false);
        returnElement = message.GetXml();

        Logger("Cert Size: " + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(cert.ToString()));

        GetBytesKeyAndData(rKey, assertion.InnerText);


        return returnElement;
    }
```