# Java analogue of php or node encryption function

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to write an encryption function in java, which is analogue of below-mentioned functions in php and node:

```
openssl_public_encrypt($gzipped_string_to_encrypt, $encrypt_data, $key_string,  OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
```

and

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const result =  crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: key,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, gzippedStringToEncrypt);
```

Main problem is - I can't find proper java analogue of RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING parameter.
I tried it like that:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
val oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
val encryptionKey = Base64.decodeBase64(keyString);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encryptionKey);
Key key = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, oaepParameterSpec);
encrypted = cipher.doFinal(gziped);
```

but result can't be decrypted with function which successfully decrypts result of php and node functions.

Comment: Have you tried answers to similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110217/is-rsa-pkcs1-oaep-padding-supported-in-bouncycastle/23888246

Comment: Not reproducible on my machine. All codes apply SHA1 as MGF1- and OAEP-digests and are compatible. You are doing something else wrong. Post a complete example so that a repro is possible, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Topaco, you're right - I was "doing something else wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the question is correct one. It gives an output which can be correctly decyphered.